# How to go through free text and store values?

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have a large excel workbook with several columns.

I want to go through one column (that contains free text) and store every word in a new sheet. (Not unique.)

Sample data (source sheet):

```
   |------A-------||------B-------||------C-------|
   | John         ||1234          ||I like stuff  |
   | John         ||1235          ||He like stuffs|
   | John         ||1236          ||I like cats   |
   | Jack         ||1237          ||I like dogs   |
   | John         ||1238          ||I like cats   |
```

Expected output (new sheet) - I would then manipulate this data to count frequency of values:

```
   |------A-------|
   | I            |
   | like         |
   | stuff        |
   | He           |
   | like         |
   | ..           |
   | cats         |
```

Suggested Approaches:

- First loop goes through and stores all values into a single string. Then the string could be split and inserted into the new worksheet? The code below would capture all fields into a single text file.
- First loop goes through each cell, splits values and then inserts split value into new worksheet?

It doesn't necessarily need to be in Excel, it could be in Access as I am working across both applications. More familiar with Excel VBA.

Code for fields into text file or csv:

```
 Sub WriteTextFile()

 'http://www.homeandlearn.org/write_to_a_text_file.html

 Dim FilePath As String
 Dim CellData As String
 Dim LastCol As Long
 Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("test").Select

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\auth.csv"

 Open FilePath For Output As #2

    For i = 1 To LastRow

        For j = 1 To LastCol

            If j = LastCol Then

            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)

            Else

            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","

            End If

        Next j

    Write #2, CellData
    CellData = ""

    Next i

 Close #2
 MsgBox ("Done")


 End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and what the problem is.  You can use either the collection object or the dictionary object to develop a list of unique words.

Comment: I just noted that in your question line, you write "unique" values, but in your example, you do NOT show unique words--i.e. "like" is repeated.  That being the case, my solution is irrelevant and I will delete it.  Please clarify exactly what you want.  And bear in mind that you should show what you have tried, the actual results, and the expected results.  Including VBA code if that is what you want.

Comment: I have clarified in the title that I am looking to capture all words in the freetext field (and not just uniques). I did add sample code into an earlier revision but appears this has been removed by someone.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this word list?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is save a list of all the words used to a csv file, you can do it fairly simply this way -- assuming all your words are in column C.  Note that I hard coded the file name in this instance, but you can change it as you require.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListWords()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim lNumWords As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim S As String

Set WS1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Get the column of free text
With WS1
    vSrc = .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
End With

'Count words so as to dim results array
With WorksheetFunction
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    S = .Trim(vSrc(I, 1))
    lNumWords = lNumWords + Len(S) - Len(.Substitute(S, " ", "")) + 1
Next I

'Capture the words
K = 0
ReDim vRes(1 To lNumWords, 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    V = Split(.Trim(vSrc(I, 1)), " ")
    For J = 0 To UBound(V)
        K = K + 1
        vRes(K, 1) = V(J)
    Next J
Next I
End With

With WS2.Range("a1").Resize(lNumWords)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

'Write results to a .csv file
WS2.SaveAs Filename:="c:\users\ron\desktop\Auth", FileFormat:=xlCSV

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ultimate goal actually is to count unique word occurences, take a look at the below code. It writes down every unique word once in column A of a new spreadsheet - as well as the word count in column B.

This is assuming your strings in column C don't involve punctuation marks - actually that words making up your strings are separated either with a space, a hyphen, or an apostrophe

Just enter your worksheet name in both sections highlighted with comments before giving it a try. You also should add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library in Tools->References

```
Sub splitNcount()
    Dim D As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set D = New Dictionary

    D.CompareMode = TextCompare

    'ENTER SHEET NAME HERE
    For Each r In Worksheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME").Range(Range("C1"), Range("C1").End(xlDown))
        mystr = Replace(r.Value, "'", " ")
        mystr = Replace(mystr, "-", " ")
        a = Split(mystr, " ")

        On Error GoTo ERREUR

        For Each elt In a
            D.Add elt, 1
        Next elt

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next r

    i = 1

    'ENTER SHEET NAME HERE
    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME"))
        For Each k In D
            .Range("A" & i).Value = k
            .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = D(k)
            i = i + 1
        Next k
    End With

    Exit Sub

ERREUR:

    D(elt) = D(elt) + 1
    Resume Next

End Sub
```